# Multiple file upload using jquery serialization works only at the second call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I experience a strange problem:
Form ajax call with multiple files and form values works perfect, but only on  the second call. First call ends up the the success: function(result) "else" condition. Second call works perfect and sends all data to the php. So I hit the submit button once and it shows up an empty error box and I hit the submit button again and everything works perfect.

How is that possible and how to solve that?

**UPDATE #1:** Found workaround, but not the solution. It works when I put `if (result==="") { $(".form-application").submit(); }` below the success function. But thats very dirty! ... and it upload all files twice! :-(

**PROBLEM SOLVED** David Knipe provided the solution!! Thank you so much!!

JQUERY:

```
    $(".form-application").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#btnSubmit2").text("Please wait...");
        $("#btnSubmit2").attr("disabled", true);    
        var files = $('#files')[0].files;
        var form = $(this);
        var error='';       
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute('6Le4Qb0UAAAAAHUPcsmVYIk7zc4XCsiBnf6oE-fP', {action: 'create_comment'}).then(function(token) {
                $('<input>').attr({
                    type: 'hidden',
                    value: token,
                    name: 'token'
                }).appendTo('form');

        for(var count = 0; count<files.length; count++)
        {
        var name = files[count].name;
        var extension = name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if(jQuery.inArray(extension, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1)
        {
            error += "Invalid " + count + " Image File"
        }
        else
        {
            formData.append("files[]", document.getElementById('files').files[count]);
        }
        }                   
        if(error == '')
        {                   
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr("action"),
                method: form.attr("method"),
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(result) {
                if (result == "0") {
                    $("#btnSubmit2").text("Thank you!");
                    $("#btnSubmit2").attr("disabled", true); 
                    $(".output_message").text("");              
                    $(':input','.form-application')
                    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
                    .val('')
                    .prop('checked', false)
                    .prop('selected', false);
                    $(".output_message").append("<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'>We have received your application!</div>");                          
                } else {
                    $(".output_message").text("");
                    $(".output_message").append("<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'>"+result+"</div>");       
                    $("#btnSubmit2").attr("disabled", false); 
                    $("#btnSubmit2").text("try again");
                }
            }
            });     
        }
        else
        {
        alert(error);
        }   
        });
        });
        return false;
    });
```

HTML:

```
      <form class="form-application" id="applicationform" method="post" action="https://<?PHP echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/include/process-application.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="crsf" value="<?=$_SESSION['crsf']?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="crsf-expire" value="<?=$_SESSION['crsf-expire']?>"/>       
      <div class="space40"></div>
      <h6>Name</h6>
      <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
      <div class="space30"></div>        
      <h6>Email</h6>
      <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Address">
      <div class="space30"></div>
      <h6>Instagram Name</h6>
      <input name="instagram" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Instagram Name">
      <div class="space30"></div>
      <h6>City & Country</h6>
      <input name="from" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Where do you live?">
      <div class="space30"></div>
      <h6>Tell us more about you</h6>
      <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Write some details about you, so we know you better."></textarea>
      <div class="space30"></div> 
      <h6>Upload some photos of yourself</h6>         
      <div class="file-field">
      <div class="btn btn-aqua">
        <input name="files" id="files" type="file" accepts="image/*" multiple>
      </div>
      <div class="file-path-wrapper">
      </div>
      <div class="space20"></div>         
      </div>      
      </div>
       <div class="col-12 text-center">
         <button id="btnSubmit2" type="submit" class="btn btn-full-rounded btn-aqua">Submit Application</button>
         <div class="space10"></div>              
         <span class="output_message"></span>   
       </div>   
       </form>
```

PHP Script /include/process-application.php

```
<?PHP
echo "0"; 
?>
```

Comment: Protip: When posting code, please fix the indentation, so that (for example) the `if(...) {` has the same indentation as the matching `}`. It makes it easier to read. Help us to help you.

Comment: "Found workaround, but not the solution." How is this not the solution? You haven't explained why you're expecting `"0"` from the server and not `""`. There's nothing here to tell us anything about the server.

Comment: /include/process-application.php just echo '0' (added in question) .. Thats the funny part, so in the first turn it doesnt even call or listen to the PHP script.

Comment: Note that there is more scope for getting useful logs. The documentation for `$.ajax` ( https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ) lists the arguments to the `success` callback. So you could do `success: function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) { ... }`. You can then `console.log('textStatus', textStatus);`, but I think it will just say "error". `jqXHR` is more interesting. There's a link to the `jqXHR` type. If my answer is right then it should have `jqXHR.status == 401`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I've figured this out. `$('<input>').attr(...);` sets the token attribute on a new `<input>` element. But this is after `var formData = new FormData(this);`, so the token doesn't get included in `formData`. Then I guess you get an authentication error, and I guess it does the authentication before it even gets to the PHP part. It would just be a HTTP401 response with no body, hence `""`. But then, on the second attempt, the `<input>` has already been created with the correct token, and this ends up being used to authenticate.

Comment: Makes sense. I moved `var formData = new FormData(this);` below the   `grecaptcha.ready(function() { ` now and the php is called at the first time - **BUT:** No POST variables arrive anymore. :-O
`echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST); 
echo "</pre>";` from the php returns just `Array()`

Comment: That's because `this` is wrong. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this . It should work if you replace the current `var formData` line with `var self = this;`, then write `var formData = new FormData(self);` in the `grecaptcha.ready(function() {` instead of `new FormData(this)`. Although personally I would have done it differently. I would have done something like `var formData = { name: $('input[name="name"]').val(), ... , token: token };`. Adding an extra thing into the UI, even if it's invisible, seems like an unnecessary layer.

Comment: It works!! Finally! I cannot thank you enough! Greetings from Greece!!

Comment: In that case could you mark this as the correct answer please? Also, in hindsight I'm not sure why it was calling the PHP code without POST variables. It must have got the token alright, and probably the authentication part didn't forward the token to the PHP code. But I don't know why it would send the token if `this` was wrong.

Comment: It worked perfect before, but only on the 2nd time. So I thave no idea why to be honest. The problem came up by adding the multiple files to the ajax call and adding the `var formData = new FormData...` for taking the files in. Without (in my contact form) I used only `var form = $(this);`and `data: form.serialize(),` but I didnt figured out how to access the uploaded files this way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Either keep onsubmit or action. Remove action from form tag, it will work

Comment: Please check again. HTML added.

Comment: hey, it is working . check here https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G9B28896DD43

Comment: Surely `e.preventDefault();` means this isn't an issue? Even if there was no `preventDefault`, I don't see how that would explain the fact it works the second time but not the first time.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. I would be happy of any suggestions. My "workaround" is completely stupid because it uploads all files twice.

Comment: e.stopImmediatePropagation(); also doesnt solve the issue. I guess it have something to do with the fact that I have form and formdata?! But to be honest I have no clue, thats why I need a specialist :-)

Comment: If it is uploading twice then $(".form-application").unbind().submit(function(e){your code})